# Grails auto-recompilation not working for bigger projects

Tags: grails-2.0

I have issues running grails using

```
grails

> run-app
```

If I change a controller file in a new project, I see those messages all the time:

```
Compiling 1 source files...
```

But as soon as i install spring security plugin, recompilation works only very rare. I assume its to do with my windows system, because I do NOT have any issues on regular linux machines (with the same project!). Do you have any ideas why auto-recompilation on windows could not work?

My setup:

- Windows 7 64bit
- JDK - tried all kind of versions, e.g. 1.6.0_25
- Solid state disk
- GRAILS_OPTS: `-XX:MaxPermSize=1G -Xmx4G -server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is directly related to the following issue http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8914.

Let's wait for grails 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

could be something wrong with your grails setup.

try to perform

> clean - compile

after that, try to run grails with

> run-app --stacktrace --verbose

and give me the result

Comment: Same behaviour - there is no special output, if I change the file :(

Comment: did you tried to run in interactive mode or just type `grails run-app --stacktrace --verbose` ?

Comment: started grails using `grails --stacktrace --verbose` and then ran `run-app`, so started in interactive mode

Comment: try go to your workspace and run `grails run-app --stacktrace --verbose` don't run it on interactive mode